# How to make two buttons in HStack the same width based on the larger button

Tags: swiftui

I am currently trying to create an `HStack` with two buttons inside:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Short") { }
            Button("Rather long") { }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}
```

The behavior I want to achieve is to make the buttons the same width. They should both have the same width as the larger of the two buttons.

[image]

I have tried the following solutions (that don't achieve the desired result):

- `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` modifier --> Only works in a `VStack`
- `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier --> Works kind of but makes the both buttons fill the full width of the screen which is not the design I want
- `.frame(width: 80.0)` --> Works kind of but breaks when changing the label to a longer word or increasing text size

Is there any other solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [layout protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Layout) from WWDC 2022 to create your own layout container:

```
struct MyEqualWidthHStack: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) -> CGSize {
        // Return a size.
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return .zero }

        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let totalSpacing = spacing.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }

        return CGSize(
            width: maxSize.width * CGFloat(subviews.count) + totalSpacing,
            height: maxSize.height)
    }

    func placeSubviews(
        in bounds: CGRect,
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) {
        // Place child views.
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return }
      
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)

        let placementProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height)
        var x = bounds.minX + maxSize.width / 2
      
        for index in subviews.indices {
            subviews[index].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.midY),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: placementProposal)
            x += maxSize.width + spacing[index]
        }
    }
    
    private func maxSize(subviews: Subviews) -> CGSize {
        let subviewSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        let maxSize: CGSize = subviewSizes.reduce(.zero) { currentMax, subviewSize in
            CGSize(
                width: max(currentMax.width, subviewSize.width),
                height: max(currentMax.height, subviewSize.height))
        }

        return maxSize
    }
    
    private func spacing(subviews: Subviews) -> [CGFloat] {
        subviews.indices.map { index in
            guard index < subviews.count - 1 else { return 0 }
            return subviews[index].spacing.distance(
                to: subviews[index + 1].spacing,
                along: .horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage like normal HStack:

```
MyEqualWidthHStack {
    Button {
        showView.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text("1")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    Button {
        showView.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text("Button2")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
struct FixedSizeButton: View {
var label = ""
var width = 100.0
var action: () -> Void
var body: some View {
    Button(action: action) {
        Text(label)
            .frame(width: width)
    }
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        FixedSizeButton(label: "Short") { }
        FixedSizeButton(label: "Rather long") { }
        
        FixedSizeButton(label: "Short", width: 200) { }
        FixedSizeButton(label: "Rather long", width: 200) { }
        
    }
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
}
```

}

Haven't checked that it does everything a button wants to do.

[image]

Comment: This solution relies on a fix button width that needs to be specified. Although this works, it can break in some cases. E.g. when dynamic type is being used and the large text needs more space than specified in the FixedSizeButton().

Comment: I used constants to keep the example short and sweet. I'm assuming the OP can parameterize the solution as required. Including calculations of the string length would have been distracting.